# Different types of USB charger attacks that work on Android phones

Tags: android, smartphone, firmware, system-compromise, badusb

I'm wondering about different types of malicious USB charger attacks that work on Android devices when USB debugging option is disabled and if the USB option is set to "charge only".

I'm not talking about Badpower attacks that aim to destroy a device. I am talking about infecting Android phone firmware with viruses. Is it possible with the mitigations I've mentioned?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If such vulnerabilities existed, that would be a pretty big deal, and would likely be fixed as quickly as possible. If they are out there, they would probably turn up with a search.